# Glob pattern include all js exclude certain endings

Tags: node.js, pattern-matching, mocha.js, glob, node-glob

I'd like to use glob with mocha. Sadly mocha does not support exclude and it does not pass glob options either, so I have to solve this in a single pattern without the usage of the glob ignore option. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1577 The other solution would be to use mocha.opts, but that is not karma compatible, I am not sure why. I could define a karma compatible opts file for karma and a node compatible opts file for node, but this will break immediately after the issue is fixed, so I am looking for another solution. https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/88

I need to match `test/**/*.spec.js` and exclude `test/**/*.karma.spec.js` from the results. Is this possible with a single glob pattern?

Comment: I tried with `"test": "mocha --reporter spec \"test/**/*(.spec.js|!(.node.spec.js))\"",` so far. It is parsed, but I got an error that cannot find module `test/features`. This is odd, because there are no `.spec.js` or node modules in that folder, only `.feature` files for BDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we are talking here is the `AND("*.spec.js", NOT("*.karma.spec.js"))` expressed with logical operators. I checked the glob documentation, it does not support the `AND` logical operator.

Lucky for us we can transform this operator to `OR` with negation: `NOT(OR(NOT("*.spec.js"), "*.karma.spec.js"))`. I tried out the `test/**/!((!(*.spec.js)|*.karma.spec.js))`, but it does not work. It tries to require a module with the `test/features` path, which is a path of a directory and not a js file, so no wonder it does not manage it. I don't know what kind of bug is that, but it is apparently not working.

Another possible solution to forget this `AND` operator, and use only negation with `NOT("*.karma").spec.js`. I tried this out with `test/**/!(*.karma).spec.js`, which was working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `mocha` and `find` **together**. For example, the following command will return a list of `test/**/*.spec.js` and exclude `test/**/*.karma.spec.js`:

```
find test -name '*.spec.js' ! -path '*.karma.spec.js'
```

Combine it with `mocha` to achieve what you want:

```
mocha $(find test -name '*.spec.js' ! -path '*.karma.spec.js')
```